# Strophe register plugin

Tags: javascript, strophe

I am trying to use this
https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/register
for my small app

http://rghost.ru/7qjXH2cTZ

and a always get Strophe.status = 1? what does it mean? It should be 11 for enter into If for register new user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify your code against my example on Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/F8cbsBZQUPiZ0W1v0O89

Here is the code part related to user registration:

```
function register() {
    var registerCallback = function (status) {
        if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTER) {
            log("registerCallback: REGISTER");
            connection.register.fields.username = $('#reg_name').get(0).value;
            connection.register.fields.password = $('#reg_pass').get(0).value;
            console.log(connection.register.fields);
            connection.register.submit();
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTERED) {
            log("registerCallback: REGISTERED");
            $('#jid').get(0).value = $('#reg_name').get(0).value + "@" + server;
            $('#pass').get(0).value = $('#reg_pass').get(0).value;
            connection.authenticate();
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            log("registerCallback: CONNECTED");
            // set presence
      connection.send($pres());
      updateConnButton(true);
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONFLICT) {
            log("registerCallback: Contact already existed!");
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.NOTACCEPTABLE) {
            log("registerCallback: Registration form not properly filled out.")
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGIFAIL) {
            log("registerCallback: The Server does not support In-Band Registration")
        } else {
            // every other status a connection.connect would receive
        }
    };

    if (!connection) {
        var url = BOSH_SERVICE;
        connection = new Strophe.Connection(url);
        connection.rawInput = rawInput;
        connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;
    }
    connection.register.connect(server, registerCallback);
}
```

Comment: I am register it using this same way, now i can able to login but the contact list is showing only the jid, no username or fullname. I am searching about this and I got the result is "vcard", but no entry in vcard table.