# Strophe connect xmpp openfire

Tags: xmpp

How can we register user in openfire via strophe? I am using registration plugin in openfire.it is working fine.I am using "test" username.

But When i tried connect with openfire fron custom.js like.

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = '/xmpp-httpbind'
connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
log(connection);
connection.rawInput = rawInput;
connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;
connection.connect('admin','admin',onConnect);
```

**Response**

```
Object { service="/xmpp-httpbind",  rid=4209744652,  do_session=false,  more...} gab.js (line 6)
Strophe is connecting. gab.js (line 6)
SENT: <body rid='4209744652' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='admin' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>gab.js (line 6)
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/xmpp-httpbind"
Error: 16, ioError, An error occured preventing completion of the request.....throwUnhandledError=function(O){throw new B.Error(O)};G.error=function(R,P,Q,O)...
```

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994662/strophe-register-plugin/35055565#35055565

Comment: Hello beaver, Thank you for your reply.it is useful.Can you help on manage session in strophe for new tabs or pages?