# Receive 'subscribe' presences with Strophe.js Roster plugin and Ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js, rosters

I'm using the [Strophe.js Roster plugin](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/roster) with [Ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) as XMPP Server. When I use [Adium](https://adium.im) or some other XMPP Clients I can add some other accounts in my Roster. When I send an invitation, the other account receives *presence* with `type=='subscribe'`.

Wit Strophe.js Roster, **I never receive any presence with `type == 'subscribe'`**!
I tried everything...I added some handlers...I "filtered"  and ...

### Here is my code :

**HTML includes**

```
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../strophe.js'></script>
    <script src="../strophe.muc.js"></script>
    <script src="../strophe.register.js"></script>
    <script src="../strophe.roster.js"></script>
    <script src='my-code.js'></script>
```

**my-code.js**

```
var jid;
$(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE, {'keepalive': true});
    //connection.rawInput = rawInput;
    //connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;

    connection.addHandler(onPresence, null, 'presence', null, null, null);
    connection.roster.registerRequestCallback(onRequest);


    // Manage connection
    try {
        $('#connect').get(0).value = 'disconnect';
        connection.restore(null, onRegister);
    } catch(e) {
        if (e.name !== "StropheSessionError") { throw(e); }
        $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    }
    $('#connect').bind('click', function () {
       var button = $('#connect').get(0);
       if (button.value == 'connect') {
           button.value = 'disconnect';

           jid = $('#jid').get(0).value;
           connection.connect(jid, $('#pass').get(0).value, onConnect, 10);
       } else {
           button.value = 'connect';
           connection.disconnect();
       }
   });
});


function onPresence(stanza)
{
    log("PRESENCE");
    console.log(stanza);

    return true;
}

function onRequest(req) {

    console.log("Request");
    console.log(req);

    return true;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994662/strophe-register-plugin/35055565#35055565 Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

> We must send a presence when the connection's status is
>   `Strophe.Status.CONNECTING`

```
function onConnect(status)
{
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
        log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
        log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
        log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
        log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        log('Strophe is connected.');


        // Send a presence to the server
        connection.send($pres().tree());

    }
}
```